# Forbidden Error Message with API GET classlist/grade calls

Tags: desire2learn

I am making an API call for the class list along with grades from D2L. I keep getting an Unknown error occured, Forbidden error message. I am able to access Profile and Organization Information through API calls but not the grades and classlist. Is this something that can my learning suite can configure?

Answer (score 1):

Since all the API calls happen within the context of a particular user's permissions, it's possible that the calling user context in which you're making the calls doesn't have the appropriate permissions to gain access to the classlist/grade information.

For example, with the classlist -- there are specific role permissions associated with having access to the classlist (see the "Classlist" role permission group): note that these permissions apply on an org unit type basis, and might need to be turned on for both course offerings and the parent org unit type (Departments, perhaps).