# Submitting a file to the Desire2Learn Dropbox via PHP

Tags: php, api, rest, dropbox, desire2learn

I'm trying to use PHP to submit a file to the [Desire2Learn](http://www.desire2learn.com) Dropbox. I've gathered the file on the proxy no problem; it's trying to transfer the file from the proxy to the Dropbox where a problem occurs. I'm using their [Valence API](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/index.html).

The user context for making this call has adequate permissions on the system to do so.

The error is "Unknown error occured".

```
$attachment=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
$attachmentName=$_FILES["file"]["name"];
$type=$_FILES["file"]["type"];
$file_name_with_full_path="files_dir/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
$file_to_upload = array('file_contents'=>'@'.$file_name_with_full_path); 

require_once 'libsrc/D2LAppContextFactory.php';
$errorArray = array(
    D2LUserContext::RESULT_OKAY => "Success",
    D2LUserContext::RESULT_INVALID_SIG => "Invalid signature.",
    D2LUserContext::RESULT_INVALID_TIMESTAMP => "There is a time skew between server and local machine.  Try again.",
    D2LUserContext::RESULT_NO_PERMISSION => "Not authorized to perform this operation.",
    D2LUserContext::RESULT_UNKNOWN => "Unknown error occured"
);

$port=443;
$host="subdomain.domain.com";

session_start();
foreach (array('appId', 'appKey', 'userId', 'userKey') as $e) {
    if (!isset($_SESSION[$e]) || $_SESSION[$e] == '') {
        die("Missing $e.  Please authenticate first.");
    }
}

$appKey = $_SESSION['appKey'];
$appId = $_SESSION['appId'];
$userId = $_SESSION['userId'];
$userKey = $_SESSION['userKey'];
session_write_close();

$authContextFactory = new D2LAppContextFactory();
$authContext = $authContextFactory->createSecurityContext($appId, $appKey);
$opContext = $authContext->createUserContext($host, $port, true, $userId, $userKey);

$target_url = $opContext->createAuthenticatedUri('/d2l/api/le/1.0/00004/dropbox/folders/00007/submissions/mysubmissions/', 'POST');

$ch = curl_init(); 

$random_hash = md5(date('r', time()));
$comment = array('Text'=>'some comment','HTML'=>null);
$comment = json_encode($comment);

$fp = fopen("files_dir/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"], 'rb');

ob_start(); //Turn on output buffering 
fpassthru($fp);
$filedata = ob_get_clean();

$request_pre="--".$random_hash."\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\n".$comment."\r\n--".$random_hash."\r\nContent-Disposition:form-data; name=\"\"; filename=".$attachmentName."\r\nContent-Type:".$type."\r\n\r\n".$filedata."\r\n--".$random_hash."--\r\n";

$request=nl2br($request_pre);

$length=strlen($request);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("HTTP/1.1", "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=".$random_hash,"Host:".$host, "Content-length: ".$length));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$target_url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, getcwd().'/cacert.pem');
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$httpCode  = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
$contentType = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);
$responseCode = $opContext->handleResult($response, $httpCode, $contentType);
$error_no = curl_errno($ch);

fclose($fp);

if ($responseCode == D2LUserContext::RESULT_OKAY) {
    $ret = "$response";
    $tryAgain = false;
} elseif ($responseCode == D2LUserContext::RESULT_INVALID_TIMESTAMP) {
    $tryAgain = true;
} else {
    $ret = "{$errorArray[$responseCode]}<br/>$response";
    $tryAgain = false;
}
if ($error_no == 0) {
    $error = 'File uploaded succesfully.';
} else {
    $error = 'File upload error.';
}
echo "error: ".$error."<br/>";


curl_close ($ch); 
echo $result;
```

The POST fields look like this (the file doesn't look right to me '86761').

```
--565cef73df4da0f072b9626f4fae7e50
Content-Type: application/json
{"Text":"some comment","HTML":null}
--565cef73df4da0f072b9626f4fae7e50
Content-Disposition:form-data; name=""; filename="example.pdf"
Content-Type:application/pdf
{86761}
--565cef73df4da0f072b9626f4fae7e50--

Unknown error occured
error: File uploaded successfully
```

Comment: And what problem actually does occur? Errors? Warnings?

Comment: Side note: since D2L is unlikely to be well known, it may be worth hyperlinking to their site and/or their API on GitHub (etc) so that readers can easily see library code.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations. I've added more detail as requested. I suspect there's a problem in how I'm implementing fopen/fpassthru but I can't see what the problem is.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11511903/forbidden-error-message-with-api-get-classlist-grade-calls) might be useful? (Found by a web search for _desire2learn "Unknown error occured"_).

Comment: Yeah, good call if I was trying to make a call that was outside of the scope of the user context's permissions; but I'm not. The user context has adequate permissions on the system to make this call (a student role submitting an assignment and a comment to the Dropbox). I will add this info into the question as it provides good context. Thanks.

Comment: There could be a problem with the JSON part you included... it's possible that you require to send a JSON object with two properties, and not simply the properties themselves: '{"Text":"test","HTML":null}'. It doesn't appear to me like you're folding your JSON properties in braces... see the example HTTP POST included in the docs here (http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/basic/fileupload.html#simple-uploads).

Comment: Good call. I've corrected that problem with the JSON block pertaining to the comment. I've also added more error checking for cURL. Note the 'file upload error'. I'm actively searching for a solution to this but if you see the problem before I post back the solution I'd be grateful for the help.

Comment: I also changed how the file is being handled in the request so that fpassthru is being caught in output buffer and that is being put into the request. The error msg is now 'Unknown error occured. error: File uploaded succesfully' but nothing appears in the Dropbox.

Comment: Hm. One of the PHP devs here suggests not to use phpcURL, but to try using HttpRequest instead: it's possible that there's something about how phpcURL is forming or sending the request that's causing issues. It's also possible that the service handling the requests doesn't like header fields missing white space between the ':' and the header field value... (that doesn't seem likely, but it's possible I suppose).

Comment: We have made this call work on a 9.4.1 test server, using a lightly edited version of your code. The dev who's done so will submit an answer to this question shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try adding a simple text file of type text/plain first to see if that works. Using your code (with some modifications) I was able to submit a file to a dropbox in Valence.

```
// read file
$fp = fopen($location, 'r');
$contents = fread($fp, filesize($location));
fclose($fp);

$request_pre="--".$random_hash."\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n{\"Text\":\"Some comment\", \"HTML\":null}\r\n\r\n--".$random_hash."\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\"; filename="."\"test1.txt\""."\r\nContent-Type: ".$type."\r\n\r\n".$contents."\r\n\r\n--".$random_hash;

$request = $request_pre; //nl2br($request_pre);

$length=strlen($request);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("HTTP/1.1", "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=".$random_hash));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$target_url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true); 
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

Just to note that I have found working with PHP Curl to be less than desirable. Consider using the [HTTPRequest](http://php.net/manual/en/class.httprequest.php) package.